# If $E[Y|X]=X$ a.s., what can one say about $\phi_X(\alpha)/\phi_Y(\alpha)$?

Tags: probability-theory

it's my first time writing here hope you can help me with this problem, it would be very appreciated.

Let $X,Y\in L_{\infty }(\Omega ,F,\mathbb{P})$be such that $E[Y|X]=X$ a.s.

Call $\phi _{X},\phi _{Y}$ the moment generating functions of X and Y. What you can say about $$\frac{\phi _{X}(\alpha )}{\phi _{Y}(\alpha )}\ ?$$

Comment: Not much, I am afraid...

Comment: Does E[f(Y)|X]=f(X)? because if so the ratio could be 1. Anyway think the ratio of the first derivatives of the MGF is 1. I can't say any further.

Comment: "Does E[f(Y)|X]=f(X)?" Not necessarily.

Comment: Suppose for instance that $Y=X+Z$ where $Z$ is independent of $X$ and $E[Z]=0$. Then the ratio is equal to $(\phi_Z(\alpha))^{-1}$. Choose all sorts of different $Z$s to convince yourself that Did's "Not much, I am afriad..." is spot on.

Comment: What do you think about my new speculations?

Comment: "so $Y$ is such that $X \leq Y$ a.s." Hmmm, why? Did you check the **definition** of conditional expectation since you posted the first version of this question?

Comment: You are right. I'll remove the update